# PrimeNG schedule locale

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I have one issue with schedule locale settings.

In it's docs ([Primeng schedule docs](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule), [Full calendar locale docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/)) says, that locale can be set up by object ({locale:'en'}), but it doesn't show any other languages, except English.

What should I do, if I want to set another language?

```
<p-schedule
                [events]="events"
                [locale]="???"
                [header]="header"
                [editable]="false"
                [allDaySlot]="false"
                [defaultView]="'agendaWeek'"
                (onEventClick)="goToSelectedEvent($event)"
                [eventRender]="eventRender"
                [contentHeight]="800"
        ></p-schedule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require "fullcalendar/dist/lang/'your language'".

And after that, you can simply add

```
this.locale = {
        locale: 'your language'
};
```

All available languages you can find here: [fullcalendar github](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/tree/master/locale)

Comment: you need to update the links. All are leading to 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

But it's right there in the documentation:

> Localization for different languages and formats is
>   defined by binding the settings object to the locale property.
>   Following is a schedule with Spanish month names.

*template*

```
<p-schedule [events]="events" [locale]="es"></p-schedule>
```

*component*

```
export class MyComponent {

    es: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.es = {
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio',
                'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']
        };
    }
}
```

Visit the [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/) documentation for the available options. Existing translations are available [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/tree/master/locale).

Comment: There are some languages in full calendar, that works fine without hardcoding them. So I need to hardcode all my locale settings?

Comment: I think you should setup an angular service which takes care of obtaining these translations

Comment: I'll try this style.

Comment: I've found new solution to this problem by adding require to lang link from full calendar. Without hard code.

Comment: @ArsenyTsypushkin You should create an own answer and accept it to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have enough reputation to write a comment, so I have to add another answer...
I'm facing the same issue at the moment and for now I just hardcoded the translations (copied from fullcalendar locale file).
But I would much rather just use the existing translations! Could you please give a little more Information on how you imported and used the locale file inside your component? I don't really know how to "require" such external javascript files inside an angular 2 application and I would much appreciate your help! :)

**EDIT:** Ok, I fiddled around a little and found a solution that is working for me:

I added a locale file to my angular-cli config (under "scripts" key) and I'm using the locale by just setting a string as [locale] input in the p-schedule component. For fine-tuning i use the "options" input and set stuff like "eventTextColor" etc. so it is not using the default one. The result looks something like that:

HTML:

```
<p-schedule [locale]="locale" [options]="options"></p-schedule>
```

your.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Options, Header, EventObject } from 'fullcalendar';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  private locale = 'de';

  private options: Options = {
    eventTextColor: '#ffffff',
    slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using webpack to load all my external libs. So I reqiure language packs over there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I use angular-cli (which also uses webpack) and I put a reference to the locale file to the "scripts" array. This also works, when I set a string as input like <p-schedule [locale]="'de'">... but there are still some flaws, like "all day" is not translated correctly and I want to change the default event colors. So is there a way to get the fullCalendar locale object and mutate some values before passing it to the p-schedule component rather than using a locale string as input?

Comment: Events options can be changed via css and eventRender function. What about locale - actually I didn't find, how to change it by your own, so, the best way is to create by your own hands =(. But you can change your language locale in lib and contribute changes to their github!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just found a way, which works good enough for me. Probably it'll help others too, so I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using primeng 2.0.6, fullcalendar 3.4.0 with "angular2-meteor" 0.7.1 library. This is what worked for me:

1. As per https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule i've set in the **scheduledemo.html** file

   ```
   <p-schedule ... locale="fr">
   ```
2. As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/ i've added the below imports in the *head* section of my index.html (this is for french)

   ```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/fr.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/locale/fr.js"></script>
   ```

If you're using angular cli, I believe those should be added in "scripts" section for .js files or "styles" for .css of file **.angular-cli.json** instead of index.html. In that file you can even reference files that are located in node_modules. For an example, you can look at the file in the lastest primeng source code (the below code will not completely solve the locale issue, it's just to give a syntax example for .angular-cli.json):

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
    ...
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
  ],
```

***Note 1:*** if you're using a single language file (like in my example) you don't even need to execute step 1. with scheduledemo.html (as per fullcalendar documentation: `If you are simply loading one locale, you do not need to specify the locale option`).

***Note 2***: If you try to use "require" to load the language file and get "Uncaught TypeError: e.fullCalendar.datepickerLocale is not a function", my solution will fix this issue. (you actually don't need to "require" at all)

Answer (score 0):

With the last version 11 you could use I18N

In the components, when use calendar:

```
// Import PrimeNgConfig
import {PrimeNGConfig} from 'primeng/api';

// Inject PrimeNgConfig
 constructor(private primeNGConfig: PrimeNGConfig) {
  }

// Init PrimeNgConfig settings, in the lang you need
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.primeNGConfig.setTranslation(
      {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        dayNames: ['domingo', 'lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mié', 'jue', 'vie', 'sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'X', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['ene', 'feb', 'mar', 'abr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dic'],
        today: 'Hoy',
        clear: 'Limpiar',
      }
    );
  }
```

in the html

```
  <p-calendar showButtonBar="true"
                          dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
                          yearRange="2000:2030"
                          formControlName="date_born"
                          inputId="date_born"
                          firstDayOfWeek="1"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: Hey what about the rest of the configurable values.  If one uses filtering on p-table then a bunch more values are needed.

Comment: This code is invalid in version 12 since Translation doesnt have a firstDayOfWeek attribute. I had to use both primeNgConfig.setTranslation and also a [locale] and a [firstDateOfWeek] property in the <p-calendar> tag.